# How to get neaby places, photos with MKLocalSearchRequest

Tags: ios, mapkit, mklocalsearch, mklocalsearchrequest

Does the response for `MKLocalSearchRequest` give you an image for each entry? Or is there a way to get the Nearby places with a place photo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search request returns an array of `MKMapItems`. Imagery is not part of the metadata included in those objects (you can see all the available information in [the class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/index.html)).

If you want to obtain photos you'll need to use some other service or API that provides them, such Foursquare, Facebook, Yelp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look into Wikipedia's API:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page